# An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, error404

soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación.

Estoy intentando hacer una app de películas, las cuales pueden ser filtradas como populares, mas valoradas, Próximamente, etc, etc. Para realizar el filtro he creado un menú desplegable, y quiero que al seleccionar un filtro en la URL cambie la palabra clave para realizar la busqueda.

En el MainActivity, antes de la clase, definí la variable donde quiero almacenarlo así (no se si es correcto hacerlo así pero es la única manera que desde otra actividad de tipo interfaz ve la variable):

```
var item2:String="popular"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

Después en la misma actividad cree la funcion que lee lo seleccionado en el menu:

```
override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long)
{
    val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
    item2=item
}
```

Luego en otra actividad leo la variable y la concateno con la URL

```
interface MovieApiInterface {
    @GET(/3/movie/$item2?api_key=KEY_NUM)
    fun getMovieList(): Call<MovieResponse>
}
```

pero al hacer esto me devuelve el error "An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant"

Podrían explicarme que hago mal?

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Pues deberías cotregir esto:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
var item2:String="popular"
```

¿Por qué? Pues básicamente porque estás declarando la variable fuera de la clase:

```
var item2:String="popular"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

Comment: ¿podrías explicar qué hace el código que pusiste?

Comment: Listo, he aclarado la respuesta